# How to use re.sub with capturing groups correctly?

Tags: python, regex

I have an URL which looks like this:

```
url = https://www.sx.com/found/text.html
```

I want to replace the text between third and fourth slash with a capturing group, i.e. I want to replace 'found' with a new string (news) like this:

```
replace = re.sub(r'(?:/.*/)(.*)/', r'/news/\1', url)
```

Desired result:

```
replace = https://www.sx.com/news/text.html
```

However I get this result:

```
https:/news/text.html
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use `re.sub(r'^(https?://[^/]*/)[^/]+/', r'\1news/', url)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/V6ueZH/2))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though you should use `urllib` to do this stuff, with re you can try

```
(//.*/).*/
```

Replace by

```
\1news/
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cuNe0j/1

Or you can try this. With this you don't need to take care of `url` parsing.

```
from urlparse import urlparse, urlunsplit
x= urlparse("https://www.sx.com/found/text.html")
y= x.path.replace("found", "news")
print urlunsplit([x.scheme, x.netloc, y,
         x.query, x.fragment])
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

```
>>> url = 'https://www.sx.com/found/text.html'
>>> print ( re.sub(r'(.+/)[^/]+(/[^/]*/?)$', r'\1news\2', url) )
https://www.sx.com/news/text.html
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(.+/)`: Greed match of 1+ of any characters followed by `/`. Capture group #1
- `[^/]+`: Match 1+ of any char that is not `/`
- (/[^/]*/?): Match next `/` followed by non-`/` character till end. Capture group #2
- `$`: End